# Does access via the API count towards Fanatic and Enthusiast badges?

Tags: support, badges, api, activity-badges

Now that the [Stack Exchange API offers user authentication via OAuth 2.0](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), if a user accesses a Stack Exchange site via the [API](https://stackapps.com/), does the access count towards the Fanatic and Enthusiast badges?

Comment: eagerly awaiting an answer bcoz i might be off to some place without my laptop soon :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, API access does not count towards any badge progress.  This is true for versions 1.x and 2.0 (all that exist at time of writing).

While I *suppose* we could change this in a future release, I very much doubt we ever will as it's *so* trivial to abuse.

Comment: I don't think a person who actually cares about the rep on site would aim at abusing this for badge acquisition. I mean installing an app just for the sake for rep is a bit far fetched.

Comment: @MozenRath - people are constantly trying to game view count (of all things), so I'm fairly confident gaming badges would be a little more widespread than you suspect.

Comment: I agree.  Far fetched indeed.  However, having gotten close to 100 visits and then having a 'visited' day not count because of a reason I found myself  thinking the same thing: "would an automatic api script get me past the fanatic badge".  So, thanks for the question and answer.