# Lost fanatic streak in the app

Tags: discussion, support, ios-app, badge-progress

A couple circumstances happened at once, making my access apparently not count. Is this correct behavior?

1. I use the iOS app a lot. I'd been refreshing the feed, but possibly not much else on that particular day. Maybe viewing the feed doesn't count? It's not terribly obvious.
2. I also keep a few bookmarks in the browser, but apparently had been logged out at some point, so those views didn't count, even though I was viewing.
3. *(For sympathy)* I haven't turned on my computer in a week because I'm on paternity leave with a newborn poop-factory blob of screaming. I'll be back to my usual active self in another two weeks.

But I've *still* been good about visiting every (UTC) day.

It's just a silly badge, but it would have been my first *gold* one. And I was almost there (about 75 days).

So I thought I'd see what the masses think regarding my particulars. Is there any recourse? Do I deserve any?

Comment: The app uses the API, which does not count as "activity" towards the badges. See [Does access via the API count towards Fanatic and Enthusiast badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75117/does-access-via-the-api-count-towards-fanatic-and-enthusiast-badges)

Comment: That sucks, but the logic makes good sense. At least now I can comfortably ignore everyone for the next few weeks! :P

Comment: The Android app records activity correctly though, so if the iOS app isn't it's either a bug/not yet implemented.

Comment: Well, 100 days later I got that darn badge. And my three month old is doing great too. Closing this question as a dupe, as the behavior has been described for the android app